# Is a question about applications that keep records of movies on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I posted a question about [which online tools can be used to keep track of movies I have already seen](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/471/what-can-be-used-as-an-already-seen-keeper). Is it on topic?

In a broader sense - would a question about IMDB.com be on-topic?

Or is it a question suited for [Super User](http://superuser.com)?

---

What about this question?

> Is there something similiar to IMDB top 250 movies?

It's not directly about movies, but one can see the connection, it's about the source of good movies.

I also did not ask on [Web Applications](http://webapps.stackexchange.com) because I guessed I can get a better answer on Movies, because of the users here.

Comment: It is good to ask the question - thank you, but personally I believe it was off topic.

Answer (score 4):

*Would questions about IMDB be on-topic?*

No, unless it is to do with a reference that IMDB has pertaining to a movie. Questions about how to use a site, specifically webapps, are off-topic.

e.g. "IMDB has the synopsis as Paul going down the stairs, I have never seen that. Is there a special release version of this movie?" << This is okay.

Your question should be closed as not constructive (or not a real question) as it is a recommendation question asking for information without showing prior research. In its current form, it is just a polling question for what is out there.

Already mentioned in the comments on that question, the correct place would be [Web Applications](http://webapps.stackexchange.com) for end users of web applications.

Though as I said earlier, there was no effort to show prior research and be closed there as well.

On another note there is a private beta movie site available in meta.webapps.stackexchange.com

https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1016/community-beta-invitation-list

see Letterboxd

Comment: I can see the problem, that it should be on web app- but I dont see the problem with constructivnes. If someone ask identify-this movie he does not need to say how did he allready searched for the film. IMHO the poll is also a question.

Comment: @Hurda I have a problem with identify-this movie as well but there is a huge group that supports it. It's an exception that seems to be working on lit.stackexchange.com and scifi.stackexchange.com

Comment: I don't have problem with identify this movie, I think it's perfect type of question, because it's hard to research if you don't know what you are looking for. Asking around is working. As is my polling question.

Comment: @hurda Polls SE wide are not welcome. So you have to bring up a valid strong case for your type of poll. As I said identify-this is an exception.

Comment: "What's the best way to aproach this problem" is valid question on StackOverflow. I also narrowed down the problem to exact cryteria - not what do you think is the best.

Comment: @hurda You did, but as the close reason states "This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, **polling**, or extended discussion" At best your question is in the form of [Let's go shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)